# multiply many 2d arrays by vector using the previous result of the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, matrix-multiplication

`a = np.array([0, 0, 1000])`

`b = np.array([[0.1,0.5,0.4],[0.2,0,0.8],[0.1,0.2,0.7]])`

`c= np.array([[0,0.5,0.5],[0.3,0,0.7],[0.1,0.4,0.5]])`

`d= np.array([[0.3,0.5,0.2],[0.4,0.3,0.3],[0.1,0.3,0.6]])`

I have this vector (a) that I need to multiply by many 2d arrays(b,c,d). How can I write a loop that takes a and multiplies by b and then uses the result, to multiply by c ,and then uses that result to multiply by d.

I am currently doing this

`result=np.dot(a,b)`

`result2=np.dot(result,c)`

`result3=np.dot(result2,d)`

But i need to be able to loop through all as I have many vectors and matrices.

**edit np.linalg.multi_dot works for this case, but I need to get the output of each array like this

````
array([130., 330., 540.])
array([225., 326., 449.])```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`multi_dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html) function:

```
np.linalg.multi_dot([a, b, c, d])
```